# AppHost.RunAsync() hangs indefinitely

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, autofac

I am trying to run my application where I have bunch of services configured (windows background service, email service, logging and some DI objects) with the help of Autofac, but the AppHost.RunAsync() hangs indefinitely and does not return the control. What is weird is the same code has worked previously. After running for a few times it started giving the above-mentioned issue. I have tried checking the RunAsync method, all the services are being registered properly and none of them seems to be giving an issue. Just to check I have commented out all the services just keeping the basic ones (logging, processoroptions), still the AppHost does not run. Could anyone please let me know the reason for this behavior?

Program.cs

```cs
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
            LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration("NLog.config");
            log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
            var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
            AppHost = builder
                 .UseServiceProviderFactory(ctx =>
                 {
                     AutofacConfiguration.Configuration = ctx.Configuration;
                     return new AutofacServiceProviderFactory(AutofacConfiguration.BuildContainer);
                 })
                .ConfigureServices((ctx, services) =>
                {                      
                    var svcOptions = ctx.Configuration.GetSection(ServiceEntryPointOptions.ConfigSectionName).Get<ServiceEntryPointOptions>();
                    WindowsBackgroundService.WindowsServiceKey = $"{svcOptions.ServiceName}${svcOptions.InstanceName}";

                    services.AddHostedService<WindowsBackgroundService>();
                })
                .UseWindowsService(options =>
                {
                    options.ServiceName = WindowsBackgroundService.WindowsServiceKey;
                })
                .Build();
            await AppHost.RunAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            AppHost?.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

AutofacConfiguration.cs

```cs
     public partial class AutofacConfiguration
     {
         public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
         public static NLog.ILogger AppLogger { get; } = LogManager.GetLogger("Logger");
    
         private static readonly ILogger Log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
   
         public static void BuildContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
         {
             #region Container configuration
    
             try
             {
                 #region Library Configuration
    
                 builder.RegisterInstance(AppLogger)
                     .As<NLog.ILogger>()
                     .SingleInstance();
    
                 #endregion
    
                 #region Application specific types
    
                 builder.RegisterOptions<ServiceEntryPointOptions>(Configuration, ServiceEntryPointOptions.ConfigSectionName);
    
                 // Used by DeadletterErrorHandler
                 builder.RegisterType<ServiceStoppingService>()
                     .As<IServiceStoppingService>()
                     .SingleInstance();
                 builder.RegisterType<LifecycleService>().As<ILifecycleAsync>();
    
                 builder.RegisterRmqConnectionManager(Configuration, RmqConnectionManagerOptions.ConfigSectionName);
                 builder.RegisterRmqMessageHandler(Configuration, RmqMessageHandlerOptions.ConfigSectionName);
                 builder.RegisterEmailNotificationServiceOptions(Configuration, EmailNotificationServiceOptions.ConfigSectionName);
    
                 #endregion
             }
             catch (Exception e)
             {
                 Log.Error(e);
    
                 throw;
             }
    
             #endregion
         }
     }
```

AutofacConfigurationExtension.cs

```cs
        public static class AutofacConfigurationExtensions
        {
           public static ContainerBuilder RegisterOptions<TOptions>(
           this ContainerBuilder builder,
           IConfiguration config,
           string sectionName,
           string name = null
           )
           where TOptions : class, new()
            {
                var section = config.GetRequiredSection(sectionName);
                var options = section.Get<TOptions>();
                var accessor = new OptionsWrapper<TOptions>(options);
    
                var item = builder.RegisterInstance(options);
                item = name switch { null => item.As<TOptions>(), _ => item.Named<TOptions>(name) };
                item.SingleInstance();
    
                var item2 = builder.RegisterInstance(accessor);
                item2 = name switch { null => item2.As<IOptions<TOptions>>(), _ => item2.Named<IOptions<TOptions>>(name) };
                item2.SingleInstance();
    
                return builder;
            } 
     public static ContainerBuilder RegisterRmqConnectionManager(this ContainerBuilder builder,
                IConfiguration config,
                string sectionName,
                string name = null)
            {
                builder.RegisterOptions<RmqConnectionManagerOptions>(config, sectionName, name);
                builder.RegisterType<RmqConnectionManager>()
                    .As<IRmqConnectionManager>()
                    .PropertiesAutowired();
               return builder;
    
            }
            
             public static ContainerBuilder RegisterRmqMessageHandler(this ContainerBuilder builder,
         IConfiguration config,
         string sectionName,
         string name = null)
     {
         builder.RegisterType<DbRepository>()
             .As<IDomainRepository>();
         builder.RegisterType<FileParser>()
             .As<IFileParser>();
         builder.RegisterType<FileReader>()
             .As<IFileReader>();                              
         builder.RegisterOptions<RmqMessageHandlerOptions>(config, sectionName, name);
         builder.RegisterType<RmqMessageHandler>()
             .As<IRmqMessageHandler>()
             .SingleInstance()
             .PropertiesAutowired();
         return builder;
     }
     
       public static ContainerBuilder RegisterEmailNotificationServiceOptions(this ContainerBuilder builder,
         IConfiguration config,
         string sectionName,
         string name = null)
      {
          builder.RegisterOptions<EmailNotificationServiceOptions>(config, sectionName, name);
    
          builder.RegisterType<EmailNotificationService>()
              .As<IEmailNotificationService>()
              .SingleInstance()
              .PropertiesAutowired();
          return builder;
      }
      }
```

Comment: _"but the AppHost.RunAsync() hangs indefinitely"_ - I see only  `await AppHost.RunAsync();` call, why do you expect it to finish?  _"still the AppHost does not run"_ -  how do you check that?

Comment: The windows service is subscribed to an event.. which keeps listening to the messages from RabbitMQ @GuruStron

Comment: `RunAsync()` definition: *Runs an application and returns a Task that only completes when the token is triggered or shutdown is triggered* [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostingabstractionshostextensions.runasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0). Is this what you mean by "hangs indefinitely"? Check your implementation of `BackgroundService` in your class `WindowsBackgroundService`. Are you implementing `ExecuteAsync()`, `StartAsync()`, `StopAsync()`?